# Utilização de % em arquivos HTML

Tags: php, html

Reparei que em algumas páginas web utilizam `%header%` e `%footer%` para meter o cabeçalho e o rodapé entre outras coisas (vi isso em temas para o OpenGame Panel), não entendi como funcionam e como o navegador vai buscar o tal *header* e *footer*.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org" />

  <title>%title%</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= "themes/Metro/style.css" />
  <link href='themes/Metro/images/favicon.ico' rel='icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=%charset%" />
  %header_code%
</head>
<body>
    %meta%
    %body%
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mostre uma página que tenha isto, poste o código.

Comment: Podem ser as marcações de um tempalte engine.

Comment: SIm sem duvida e de algum template engine mas n entedi como funciona.

Comment: Postei um exemplo.

Comment: Qual extensão é o arquivo?

Comment: a extensao e .html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto é usado pelo software no servidor. O navegador não tem como fazer isto diretamente (pelo menos não assim como está falando). Basta você olhar no fonte da página no navegador e verá que não tem isto na página, a substituição já foi feita no servidor antes de entregar para o navegador.

Até é possível usar o JavaScript para realizar esta substituição, mas não é comum. Se precisar substituir com JS tem outras formas, coloquei a título de curiosidade.

Isto normalmente é feito como uma forma de macro substituição de texto. Esse tal Open Game Engine sabe como proceder com isto.

Ele certamente fará o [*parsing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) ([em português](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_sint%C3%A1tica_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))) da página e fará um substituição simples desta variável pelo conteúdo que ele tem configurado em algum lugar.

Isto pode ser feito com um simples [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) ou até com uma função bastante elaborada de *parse*.

O uso do caractere `%` serve para determinar que aquilo é uma variável de gabarito e não um conteúdo normal. É por este caractere que o *engine* irá procurar para fazer a substituição.

Sugiro inspecionar o código do *engine* para ver detalhes na implementação específica.