# Como usar {} ao invés de abrir tags PHP?

Tags: php

Vejo em vários sites de MuOnline, assim como em outros, vejo o pessoal utilizar ao invés de `<? SERVER_NAME; ?>`   eles utilizam `{#SERVER_NAME}`, sem abrir tags PHP.

Ao invés de utilizarem `<? include("menuLeft.php"); ?>` eles utilizam  `{#INCLUDE:menuLeft}`.

Eu não estou entendendo nada, alguém sabe me dizer como eu faço isso também?

Comment: Provavelmente e quase igual a minha questao anterior sobre os % em html, Isso provavelmente e algum sistema de templates http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76192/utiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-em-arquivos-html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Provavelmente esse site está usando [Smarty](https://www.smarty.net/syntax_comparison).

O Smarty é um *template engine* que por baixo dos panos converte o arquivo para a marcação do PHP, permitindo que você use uma sintaxe mais simplificada.

Veja um exemplo utilizando PHP puro e outro utilizando Smarty

Em PHP:

```
<?php if(!empty($foo)): ?>
  <?php foreach($foo as $bar): ?>
     <a href="<?=$bar['zig']?>"><?=$bar['zag']?></a>
     <a href="<?=$bar['zig2']?>"><?=$bar['zag2']?></a> 
     <a href="<?=$bar['zig3']?>"><?=$bar['zag3']?></a> 
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
   There were no rows found.
<?php endif; ?>
```

Smarty:

```
{foreach $foo as $bar}
  <a href="{$bar.zig}">{$bar.zag}</a>
  <a href="{$bar.zig2}">{$bar.zag2}</a>
  <a href="{$bar.zig3}">{$bar.zag3}</a>
{foreachelse}
  There were no rows found.
{/foreach}
```

Além do Smarty, existem outras *template engines* para PHP. O propósito é o mesmo: simplificar a sintaxe de templates com PHP. A diferença entre eles está basicamente na sintaxe e talvez em algumas funcionalidades específica, mas no geral elas resolvem o mesmo problema:

- [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/) - acompanha o [Symfony](https://symfony.com/)
- [Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade) - acompanha o [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs)
- [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) - sua sintaxe é usada em várias linguagens