# Utilização da tag de abertura de php <?= ?>

Tags: php, html-tags

A *tag* de abertura `<?= ?>` pode ser utilizada em sintaxes grandes? Ou só em sintaxes de impressão simples como:

```
<?= 'meu nome é xxxxxxxx' ?>
```

Comment: Duplicada? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89835/129

Comment: A resposta resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

Impressionantemente nenhuma das perguntas já feitas sobre o assunto responde isto especificamente.

Pode usar em qualquer situação, mas deve evitar se pretende rodar em versões inferiores a 5.4 em algum provedor de hospedagem que não tenha controle se elas estão ativas ou não.

Ver mais em:

- [Diferença entre tags do php <?php e <?=](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89835/101)
- [Em PHP o que esta tag <?= ?> representa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103178/101)
- [Código fonte é exibido na tela e não é executado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60365/101)
- [Como usar {} ao invés de abrir tags PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/76502/101)