# É correto concatenar PHP no JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, html5

Eu uso frequentemente este método, mas não sei se é apropriado, para resgatar o id no JS eu uso o echo php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src ="js/jquery.js"></ script>
<script type ="text/javascript">

$("document").ready(function(){
    $('.artigo-<?=$artigo['artigo_id']?>').click(function(){
        /* executa funçao */
     });
});
</ script>

<? php
$ artigo[] = array (); 
$ artigo['artigo_id'] = 1;
?>

<a class="artigo-<? = $artigo['artigo_id']?> " href =" javascript: void (0); ">executar</a>
```

Comment: Na verdade isso é concatenar JavaScript no PHP ;)

Comment: A grosso modo, está concatenando um texto em outro texto pois javascript não enxerga o php e vice-versa. No mais, não há problema algum em fazer isso. apenas recomendo que siga um padrão de sintaxe. Por exemplo, há espaçamentos no cifrão das variáveis e outros locais sem necessidade.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 11):

Não há problema em fazer isso, tudo que está entre `<?php ?>` e `<?= ?>` será interpretado pelo PHP, o resto é só um texto qualquer que será enviado ao servidor HTTP e consequentemente ao navegador sem modificação.

Lembre-se apenas que o código que você está escrevendo é o PHP. É possível intercalar textos livres dentro do código PHP em uma técnica conhecida como *templating*. Note que este é um texto que o PHP não tem nenhum conhecimento, pode ter o que quiser ali. É claro que não faz sentido pôr qualquer coisa ali, faz sentido colocar HTML e muito eventualmente CSS e/ou JS.

Não costuma ser bom misturar CSS e JS no HTML a não ser em raros casos muito bem pensados e de forma bem restrita. Esse é um caso em que provavelmente deveria ter a maior parte do JS/jQuery em outro arquivo trabalhando com parâmetro para receber o tal do `artigo_id`. Até não seria um absurdo ter no HTML a chamada para a função que faz isto.

Evidentemente espero que esse código seja só um exemplo. Ele não faz nada útil na forma como foi colocado. Daria para ser bem mais simples.

[Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107405/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado @bigown este é apenas um exemplo, estou em um dispositivo móvel e criei o código de forma rápida

Answer (score 3):

De início é bom esclarecer que "Concatenar PHP no JS" talvez não seja a melhor descrição do que ocorre aí, acredito que o termo mais correto seria algo como "Dinâmicamente gerar JS com PHP", afinal o que ocorre é que você cria partes de javascript printando (echo) conteúdo do PHP.

Respondendo a questão: dependendo do seu caso eu diria que é a opção mais apropriada sim. Se você tem um JS pequeno, digamos algo como seu exemplo de umas 20 linhas ou menos, e ele precisa manipular dados que estão no server-side (php), dar um echo e pegar o conteúdo que você precisa do PHP é simplesmente a maneira mais simples, se funciona e é código legível não tem porque alguém reclamar.

Caso seu JS tenha um tamanho razoável a situação já muda, ter uma mega bloco de javascript no meio de PHP code é algo que eu considero pavoroso, destoa completamente do código em volta, é difícil de ler e é algo que nitidamente quebra separação de responsabilidades. Neste caso eu recomendo colocar o JS no devido lugar, um arquivo .js separado, e para você ter acesso aos valores phpnianos (heh que palavra infeliz) de que precisa existem três opções:

1. Ajax, seu javascript faz um request para o server pedindo os valores de que precisa. É uma solução "pura" visto que você não mistura php e javascript diretamente, porém é a mais inchada já que você vai ter que ter um bloco AJAX no js, um php endpoint ("url que o ajax vai chamar") e uma request extra que o cliente vai ter que fazer após carregar a página.
2. No php faça echo dos dados que o js precisa como value de um input hidden, ex: `echo '<input id="mypreciousdata" type="hidden" value="' . $var . '" />';` e no js você faz algo tipo `console.log($("#mypreciousdata").val());`. Esta também é uma solução "pura" em termos de separação de código, não gera overhead como ajax e é razoávelmente simples.
3. No php gere um JS que tem os dados armazenados em algum objeto global, ex: `echo '<script>var MeuApp = {data1: "' . $var . '", data2: "' . $var2 . '"};</script>` e no seu JS basta acessar a tal variável `console.log(MeuApp.data1);`. Essa costuma ser minha estratégia mais usada pois considero a pragmática. Embora misture código js e php para inserir os dados no objeto serão apenas algumas poucas linhas de código nisso, estando o grosso do seu js que vai usar os dados em um arquivo separado.